# Selenium Webdriver Chrome Fails on Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a simple code with selenium webdriver chrome on Cloud Function. I get the following error

Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

How do I specify chromedriver executable in Cloud Function?

Below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
def test_webdriver(event=None, context=None):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
    time.sleep(5)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
```

Answer (score 3):

Headless Chrome is not currently available in the Cloud Functions runtime.

If you have the ability to switch to the Node.js runtime for your Cloud Function, you could use [`puppeteer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) which includes headless Chrome, but there is no equivalent for Python.

Another alternative would be to use Cloud Run instead of Cloud Functions. See here for an example: https://dev.to/di/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp

Comment: Is Pyppeteer not the equivalent? https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/

Comment: Unfortunately pyppeteer does not currently work on Cloud Functions Python runtimes.